# Calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier always returns a full-screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Is it possible to add a `UIViewController` to a `storyboard`, which when created using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` will return the size specified in the `storyboard`?  Or does this break the rules of `autolayout` in storyboards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the view controllers on story board is set only for design purposes and it has nothing to do on how they'll appear in the app. For that you have to set the frame of the view controller's view with `self.view.frame = CGRectMake(...`